# How to replace a tag in html string to Vue 3 Component in Nuxt.js 3 project?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, server-side-rendering, nuxtjs3

I'm using Nuxt.js v3.7.4 (SSR Mode), I have a response from api is a html string of a WYSIWYG editor like this

```html
<div>
<custom-poll id="9" />
</div>
```

and I have a component **Poll.vue** that I want to use for replacing `<custom-poll id="9" />` to `<Poll id="9" />`, I researched and I tried to use `<Component :is="{template:...}" />` but it become flickering (it show up in 1 - 2 seconds then disappear from the DOM)

here is the demo of my issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-bygkhd?file=nuxt.config.ts,app.vue,pages%2Findex.vue,components%2FPoll.vue

I want to replace the `<custom-poll id="9" />` to `<Poll id="9" />` **Poll.vue** component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see the warn in console:

`[Vue warn]: Component provided template option but runtime compilation is not supported in this build of Vue. Configure your bundler to alias "vue" to "vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js".`

Then add this config to `nuxt.config.ts`

```
  vue: {
    runtimeCompiler: true,
  },
```

Here is [docs](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/nuxt-config#runtimecompiler).

Answer (score 0):

I still recommend using `<component />` tag and resolve the bug. but if this isn't working,
you can always use v-if like this =>
`<custom-poll v-if="condition" id="9"></custom-poll>`
and at the next line =>
`<poll v-else id="9"></poll>`

Comment: you mean in the WYSIWYG, at the HTML source of the content, I need to add one more line is `<poll v-else id="9" />` ? My rich text editor is TinyMCE and when I add a new poll inside an article, there was not a vue 3 component, I just set a html  to mark that position inside article detail will have a poll